# How can I prove that if Lim(xn) = x < Lim(yn) = y, then xn < yn?

Tags: proof-writing

I started out saying to fix e > 0 and that there exists N such that for all n >= N, |xn - x| < e and |yn - y| < e. But I don't know how to go from there, i.e. how can I utilize the x < y part to continue with my proof? Thank you!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: **Hint:** Since $x<y$, you know there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<\delta<y-x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That misses the important information: For almost all $n$, so for all $n>N$ for some $N$. Any easy proof: Consider: If for any $N$ theres is a $n>N$ so that $x_n\geq y_n$ then you can find subsequences $x_{n_k} \geq y_{n_k}$. Also as $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to $x,y$ these subsequences have the same limits.

Now, as the limit is monotonous this would mean that $x\geq y$.

If you want to continue your path: Find some $N$ so that for $n>N$ you have $|x_n-x|< (y-x)/2$ and $|y_n-y|< (y-x)/2$. Then $x_n < x+(y-x)/2 = y-(y-x)/2 < y_n$.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to include that part though I had it written down for some reason. Yes, that makes much more sense, thank you dearly!